# Update a DataGridView column value in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a grid with 6 columns all are of type string now my requirement is when the user double clicks on the 6th column a new form will open and return the value from the selected record in id, name variables.

It is opening the form and getting the values but when executing the following line

```
grdItemDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = id;
```

it is not updating the field give the error and close how to update the value for this column please help. The full code is as follows.

```
private void grdItemDetail_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            frmWarehouseList frmWarehouseList = new frmWarehouseList();
            frmWarehouseList.ShowDialog();
            string id = frmWarehouseList.SelectedWarehouseID;
            string name = frmWarehouseList.SelectedWarehouseName;
            //MessageBox.Show(grdItemDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            grdItemDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = id;
        }
```

Comment: **WHAT** is the error you're getting? We cannot read your screen nor your mind - you'll have to tell us...

Answer (score 3):

The column index is zero based, so if you have six columns, the highest index is five.

Quick fix:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
{
  // etc
}
```

Comment: heh, that is probably the issue, nice catch. Might be worth adding the fact that you can refer to dgv columns by name to the answer too, to avoid the issue reoccuring if new columns are added.